# PHP updating a value in a file

Tags: php, file-handling

I have a PHP script and a file. The file only contains "8". I need to update this value to "9" using the PHP script (or any value, just incrimenting what is in the file by 1).

Currently I have a file that looks like this:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("numberFile", file_get_contents("numberFile")[0]++);
?>
```

This should write to the file what ever it reads from the first line + 1. However it doesn't work. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: just because you can write it in one line does not mean its a good idea, break it won in to 3 steps.

Comment: `file_get_contents` returns a string, not an array. You can index a string as an array, and you can use [operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) on a string. Just be aware of the side effects.

Comment: I have broken it down, but it still does not work.

Comment: The indexing is to remove the line break the file ends in.

Comment: I repeat, `file_get_contents` returns [**a string**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr), not an *array of strings*.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using a database? Or is it because you can't use one? @HCook You could even track a lot more than just hits by using a database; *just saying*. Seems like you're using this as a counter.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I didn't think to use a database for only this one bit of data. I have had some bad experiences with databases and try to stay away from them, especially as the files here move from server to server regularly.

Comment: Yeah, I agree using a database for a simple counter is overkill. As I said, I was just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content = file_get_contents('numberFile');
if (isset($content))
{
    $number = intval($content);
    file_put_contents('numberFile', ++$number);
}
```

Un-tested, but I suspect this is close to something you want, if not exactly. :)

As stated in a comment, don't try to do it all on one line, break up the code so its readable.

Comment: This still does not seem to work... Also I know that the file has a number in it.

Comment: I just tested this locally. It works. I would suggest checking to see if you have permission to open the file with `file_get_contents()`. Do a var_dump($content) and see what it outputs in your browser. If nothing, or error, then make sure you change the permissions so the web server can access the file

Comment: It works when I run it in a separate file, but not in the file it is in. But this code does work. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like the path to your file is incorrect then. Make sure the file path maps correctly too. if it works in a test script, then everything is fine. There will be a problem with the way you're accessing `numberFile` from the real script.

Comment: Another point, just because you know the file has a number in it, doesn't mean you shouldn't check for, or cast the value. Even if you are 100% that the file will only ever contain a number, still put the check in. It's a good habit to get in to and it could help headaches in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you are doing will work, but you have to be **very** careful.

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns a *string*, not an *array of strings* (you could use [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) for that).

You can also [index a string as an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr), and you can use [operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) on a string.

```
// This should print '3'
$text = '3
';
echo $text[0] . "\n";

// This should print '3' too
$text = '33';
echo $text[0] . "\n";

// This should be '4'
echo $text[0] + 1 . "\n";

// What about this ?
$text = '9';
// Now it rolls to two digits. What then ?
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/6mgWU)

The proper way to do it is cast the *whole* string as a number using `intval`.

Comment: Thanks, I was slightly confused by what you said earlier, but I get it now. I am no longer indexing.

Comment: @HCook no prob! the documentation would have taken you there eventually !